# Slick slider centerMode

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel, slick.js

I've been trying to create something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImQ4a.png) using slick.js, and i really can't get my head around it.

I have got the current code in place. How to make the center slide image 100% width and height and add paddings to the slide? It seems to be not working.

I'd really appreciate any help. Thanks.

```js
$('.slider').slick({
  centerMode: true,
  centerPadding: '30px',
  slidesToShow: 3,
  adaptiveHeight: false
});
```

```css
.slick-slide img {
  max-width: 100%; 
  transition: transform 0.5s; 
 }

.slick-slide.slick-center img{
  transform: scale(2.1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.js"></script>


<div class="slider">
  <div class="slider__item">
    <img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c849132/v849132998/45c5c/RSTineyyvfE.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="slider__item">
    <img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c849132/v849132998/45c5c/RSTineyyvfE.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="slider__item">
    <img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c849132/v849132998/45c5c/RSTineyyvfE.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="slider__item">
    <img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c849132/v849132998/45c5c/RSTineyyvfE.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="slider__item">
    <img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c849132/v849132998/45c5c/RSTineyyvfE.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="slider__item">
    <img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c849132/v849132998/45c5c/RSTineyyvfE.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

A little bit of CSS should help you out:

```js
$('.slider').slick({
  centerMode: true,
  centerPadding: '30px',
  slidesToShow: 3
});
```

```css
.slick-slide > div {
  transform: scale(.5);
  transition: transform .3s cubic-bezier(.4,0,.2,1);
}
.slick-center > div {
  transform: scale(1);
}
.slider__item > img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.js"></script>


<div class="slider">
  <div class="slider__item">
    <img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c849132/v849132998/45c5c/RSTineyyvfE.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="slider__item">
    <img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c849132/v849132998/45c5c/RSTineyyvfE.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="slider__item">
    <img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c849132/v849132998/45c5c/RSTineyyvfE.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="slider__item">
    <img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c849132/v849132998/45c5c/RSTineyyvfE.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="slider__item">
    <img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c849132/v849132998/45c5c/RSTineyyvfE.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="slider__item">
    <img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c849132/v849132998/45c5c/RSTineyyvfE.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

The principle is simple: use `transform: scale(n)` to scale down all the slides (where `n` is your desired factor - `.5` in the example above). use `transform:scale(1)` on the centered one (has `.slide-center` class) to render it at its real scale (1:1).
And add a `transition` on `transform`.

Done.