# How to get slick slider to smooth transition in a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, sass, slick.js

So I have built a slider using pretty much the same code as Andrei has done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51750461/10175775).

That's all great... but do you notice the transition when you scroll around back to the first slide, it jumps?

Does anyone know how I can fix this? I have been trying different things but nothing seems to work.

I would like it to transition smoothly all the way around the slider loop with no jumps when loading the next image.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```js
$('.slider').slick({
  centerMode: true,
  centerPadding: '30px',
  slidesToShow: 3
});
```

```css
.slick-slide>div {
  transform: scale(.5);
  transition: transform .3s cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .2, 1);
}

.slick-center>div {
  transform: scale(1);
}

.slider__item>img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.js"></script>


<div class="slider">
  <div class="slider__item">
    <img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c849132/v849132998/45c5c/RSTineyyvfE.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="slider__item">
    <img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c849132/v849132998/45c5c/RSTineyyvfE.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="slider__item">
    <img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c849132/v849132998/45c5c/RSTineyyvfE.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="slider__item">
    <img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c849132/v849132998/45c5c/RSTineyyvfE.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="slider__item">
    <img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c849132/v849132998/45c5c/RSTineyyvfE.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="slider__item">
    <img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c849132/v849132998/45c5c/RSTineyyvfE.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Here you can find an interesting ticket about that bug: https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/pull/3307 Maybe it can be helpful also for you.

Comment: Fantastic, this solved my issue! Don't know why I never thought of checking the tickets haha. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Yeeee! You're welcome! :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I just changed my css so that I was directly targeting .slick-center through .slick-slide and this seemed to do the trick!

No idea why this didn't work before as I had it set up in pretty much the same way but for some reason .slick-center has to be targeted through .slick-slide instead of independently for it to be picked up and work smoothly.

Thanks for the link to [this](http://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/pull/3307) [ReSedano](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6588621/resedano)!

:)

Comment: " but for some reason .slick-center has to be targeted through .slick-slide instead of independently for it to be picked up and work smoothly." Perhaps because of css selection specificity?

Answer (score 2):

Kindly add slick slider options:

```
speed:1300,
infinite: true,
```

```js
$('.slider').slick({
  centerMode: true,
  centerPadding: '30px',
  slidesToShow: 3,
  speed:1300,
  infinite: true,
});
```

```css
.slick-slide>div {
  transform: scale(.5);
  transition: transform .3s cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .2, 1);
}

.slick-center>div {
  transform: scale(1);
}

.slider__item>img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.js"></script>


<div class="slider">
  <div class="slider__item">
    <img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c849132/v849132998/45c5c/RSTineyyvfE.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="slider__item">
    <img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c849132/v849132998/45c5c/RSTineyyvfE.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="slider__item">
    <img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c849132/v849132998/45c5c/RSTineyyvfE.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="slider__item">
    <img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c849132/v849132998/45c5c/RSTineyyvfE.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="slider__item">
    <img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c849132/v849132998/45c5c/RSTineyyvfE.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="slider__item">
    <img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c849132/v849132998/45c5c/RSTineyyvfE.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you kindly for this but do you see on the 6th click of the 'next' button, it still seems to jump larger than the other slides rather than smoothly transitioning larger?  I can't seem to figure out what is causing this :(

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.slider').slick({
  centerMode: true,
  centerPadding: '30px',
  slidesToShow: 3,
  useTransform: false,
});
```

Adding a **useTransform: false** option above, solve the flickering transition problem for me.

Answer (score -1):

Just had the same issue.

Changed my animation to target the class .slick-center rather than .slick-current which resolved this issue.